# What makes keyboard suddenly stop working when BIOS is loading?

Tags: boot, laptop, keyboard, bios

My **laptop keyboard** when starting up **sometimes** cannot be used to access BIOS. To work around this, I simply remove the battery to reset it. This suggests that the problem lies in the software, not hardware.

Why is that? I cannot find the reason for it on the internet. I haven't used an USB keyboard to test, but I don't think it's because of my keyboard. I have used my laptop for nearly 7 years, and the problem has just happened for some weeks ago.

Here is the screenshot of my BIOS:

[image]

Comment: Try to update your BIOS (or reinstall the existing version if you're already at the latest): http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/54931-3-keyboard-suddenly-stopped-working-boot-access-bios

Comment: thanks. Although I'm looking for a permanent fix, I also want to know deeper on computer. Why does this happen?

Comment: Who knows :) Possibly because of brocken BIOS?

Comment: you mean it's a physical damage?

Comment: No, why? The BIOS is a piece of software, it can be corrupt - need to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the touchpad. Since my laptop is old, it's always jiggling and I have to completely turn it off in Windows. Simply detaching the cable solves this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The spec is old. Troubleshooting this as per below:

1. Try other keyboard and restart back to bios if this resolve
2. Perhaps this is the corruption to the BIOS software. Install the same firmware to your current version of motherboard or update motherboard BIOS if suggested fixed to the log of motherboard manufacturer itself.
3. If this cant be resolve, please check your USB port. There might be problem
4. If this cant be resolve, then we know the motherboard hardware problem. This need to change to new motherboard as this might a sign that your motherboard can be used or got a capacitor problem to the main connection circuit diagram accessing the port to the CPU

Hope this answer your question

Comment: it turns out that **installing a different OS** solves the problem (mine is the downgrading Windows 8 to Windows 7). Do you know why this happens?